# Reading of netcdf files in Spark 3 through Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have used [SciSpark](https://scispark.jpl.nasa.gov/) for reading numerous netcdf files in Spark 2.x. However, I am unable to compile it for Spark 3.x (due to various types of errors such as `cannot be applied to (Array[Int])`, `found   : Array[Long]` with `required: Array[Int]`, `cannot be applied to (AnyVal)`, etc.). Unable to even conclude if it is compatible with Spark 3. Could anyone please suggest if:

- SciSpark is compatible with Spark 3, and
- Any alternative to SciSpark in Spark 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like https://github.com/SciSpark/SciSpark isn't updated to use Spark 3 because last commit was 4 year ago.

Comment: True, that makes it unlikely to be compatible but does not rule out that with some minor changes in the build process it may be possible to integrate with Spark 3. I tried some, got a little success too, but not much.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Spark cluster you can use [Apache Sedona](http://sedona.apache.org) to read netcdf files. Documentation about netcdf files is sparse, but you can ask questions in their mailing list.

Comment: Will check. Looks interesting, thank you!